# Precision issues when reverting normalization operation

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I'm doing some normalization operation and, for my surprise, when trying to revert the operation I get a mismatch of 100% for the default 6 decimal precision of `assert_array_almost_equal`. Why is this occurring? Can it be due to the precision of my maximum value? If so, how can I get more precision in `numpy.ndarray.max()`?

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy

_max = numpy.float128(67.1036) # output of numpy.ndarray.max() on an a float32 array

def divide_and_mult(x, y):
    return numpy.divide(numpy.float128(x), y) * y

for i in range(100):
    try: numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(divide_and_mult(i, _max), numpy.float128(i))
    except AssertionError, e: print e
```

Comment: "the default 6 decimal precision of assert_array_equal" <- I think you must be confusing the `assert_array_equal` function with something else. There's no such default: `assert_array_equal` checks for _exact_ equality, with no tolerance.

Comment: Yes, you're right Mark, I was referring to 'assert_array_almost_equal' function from numpy.testing which I used in another experiment to see the mismatch percentage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get more precision with numpy arrays than `float128`, on most systems the best is even lower: `float64`.

Normally you just don't care about a bit loss in precision and use [`np.testing.assert_almost_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html#numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal) or similar functions that let you test for a specific absolute and/or relative difference.

In case you want to do it with much higher precision you need to use a type that has infinite or at least user-defined precision: [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) or [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) or switch to a symbolic math library like [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).